# AppStoreConnect - Disable "following build has completed processing" email?

Tags: app-store-connect

Each time one of my build is uploaded to TestFlight, I receive an email soon after telling me that my build has completed processing. I would prefer not too, just for the sake of useless notifications (we have a daily build sending our app into our inner TestFlight).

I tried disabling "app state reports" in AppStoreConnect/users but it has no effect. I also tried to disable "emails" in the TestFlight app, but it seems it is more regarding when a new version is available for me in TestFlight.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Why not just use Mail Rules to throw it in the Trash, marked read?

Comment: @Tetsujin while it would work, it would be cleaner to just disable them if possible, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from the Apple support, there is no such option.